# Scrapy - input processor

Tags: python, scrapy

items.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose

def filter_spaces(value):
    return value.strip(" ").strip("\n")

class LotItem(scrapy.Item):
    num = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(filter_spaces))
```

spider.py:

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    item = LotItem()                    
    item['num'] = response.xpath('//div/span/text()').extract()[0]
    yield item
```

`response.xpath('//div/span/text()').extract()[0]`  returns a kind of

```
"\n1234     "
```

And I need to turn it into: `"1234"`

But I still get object in the form - `{'num': '\n1234       '}`

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: *"my code failed"* is not a valid problem description. Please post the **full text** of any tracebacks or errors, and *clearly* describe what is happening, and how it is different from what you would like to happen. Also, have you tried the [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) function?

Comment: there is no any errors of course.. I just get {'num': '\n1234         '} rather than {'num': '1234'} as I expect to get. And of course I use exactly strip() for getting rid of some spaces

Comment: ok... I've managed with strip()... I just added it to extract()[0].strip() and this is solution... but there is similar problem - there is other property CITY ... and it often looks in object like {"city": "G\u00fcnzburg"} due to german language... I've tried extract()[0].encode('utf-8') but this didn't help..?? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use response.xpath with a regular expression instead of extract(). Something like this for the number:

```
response.xpath("//div/span/text()").re(r"(?:'num':\s'\\n)([0-9]*)(?:\s*')")
```

or something like this for the city:

```
.re(r'(?:\\"city\\":\s\"G\\\)(.*)(?:\\")')
```

(All regular expressions are untested and may need slight tweaking.)